# Free a char* that was malloc'd by a function

Tags: c, memory, malloc, free

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char* mkstr(char str1[], char str2[])
{
        char* out = malloc(sizeof(*str1) + sizeof(*str2) + 1);
        strcpy(out, str1);
        strcat(out, str2);

        return out;
}

int main()
{
        char* str = mkstr("i use ","arch btw");
        printf("%s\n",str);
}
```

When `main()` calls `mkstr()`, `mkstr()` will malloc a `char*` called `out`. How can I `free(out)` properly from this code? Can I just leave it be, or will the OS just free up the malloc'd space?

Is this the best way to do it, or are there better ways of doing it?

I'm on Linux (if that's relevant).

Comment: `sizeof(*str1)` compiles on my machine without segfaults, so what's the difference between `sizeof(*str1)` and `strlen(str1)`?

Comment: A program that compile fine is not necessarily correct. And a program that appears to run fine is not necessarily correct either. Assuming you're on a 64 bit platform, `sizeof(*str1) + sizeof(*str2) + 1` is 17. The combined lengths of `"i use `"and `"arch btw"` is 14 which is smaller than 17, therefore the size of the buffer allocated is lerge enough and the program works. Now if your strings are much longer, the you malloc still allocates only 17 bytes and you get a buffer overflow which results in _undefined behaviour_ (google that term).

Comment: Unrelated (and possibly not a concern at this point): if `str1` is *gigantous* there can be a significant efficiency loss with `strcat()` (see [schlemiel algorithm](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2001/12/11/back-to-basics/))

Comment: @pmg correct, but that's probably not a big concern to the OP at his stage of knowledge.

Comment: Please do not edit solution announcements into the question. Accept (i.e. click the "tick" next to it) one of the existing answer, if there are any. You can also create your own answer, and even accept it, if your solution is not yet covered by an existing answer. Compare https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sizeof(*x)` is the size of a pointer on your platform. It's usually 4 on a 32 bit platform and 8 on a 64 bit platform.

To get the length of a string you need to use the `strlen` function.

Corrected code:

```
char* mkstr(char str1[], char str2[])
{
        // you need to use strlen to get the length of a string
        char* out = malloc(strlen(str1) + strlen(str2) + 1);

        strcpy(out, str1);
        strcat(out, str2);
        return out;
}

int main()
{
        char* str = mkstr("i use ","arch btw");
        printf("%s\n",str);
        free(str);           // simply free str
}
```

Comment: One small nitpick here: sizeof(*x) is not the size of the pointer but the size of the object pointed at (e.g. `char *blah = "Test"; size_t blah_size=sizeof(*blah);` would set `blah_size` to the value equal to `sizeof(char)` while `sizeof(blah)` would indeed return the size of the pointer.

Comment: Oh, and I forgot: In order to avoid potential confusion and keep a door open for refactoring and extension, I recommend to create a deallocator for each allocator created. In this case: Wrap `free()` in a function like `freestr` to have the freedom to change inner workings of the library and maybe even change allocation behaviour without the client noticing.

Answer (score 1):

#### Theory:

Every heap allocated object should be freed, before exiting the application (most of the modern operating system manages the heap allocation even if you didn't freed them at exiting the application). By the way freeing heap resources is a good practice though.

#### Problems in your code:

1. Parameters for `mkstr` function should be `(const char *str1, const char *str2)` instead of `(char str[], char str2[])`.
2. Use `calloc` instead of `malloc` for better safety.
3. Use `strlen` function to determine the length of the string, instead of `sizeof`.
4. Set `void` or `(int argc, char const **argv)` as the parameter of `main` function.

#### Now `free` heap allocations:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *mkstr(const char *str1, const char *str2)
{
    char *out = calloc((strlen(str1) + strlen(str2) + 1), sizeof(char));
    strcpy(out, str1);
    strcat(out, str2);
    return out;
}

int main(int argc, char const **argv)
{
    char *str = mkstr("i use ", "arch btw");
    printf("%s\n", str);
    free(str); // freed the heap allocated resource before exiting
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: _"Use calloc instead of malloc for better safety"_: the usage of `malloc` is perfectly safe if used correctly.

Comment: How is `calloc` "safer" than `malloc`?

Comment: @lemuria it isn't safer at all. `calloc` initializes the allocatd memory with 0, but that doesn't make it any safer.

Comment: `calloc()` gives you a zero-initialized buffer, while `malloc()` leaves the memory uninitialized, which **may** cause issue.

Comment: Assume if he allocate 64 bytes and write only 32 bytes and didn't append `\0` at the end then it will cause problems

Comment: I enclosed `safer` in quotes, Jabberwocky.

Comment: Yes, @Darth-CodeX , it might be more "defensive" to use calloc, if it is not guaranteed, memory is initialized properly. In the particular case above, however, the `\0` terminal is guaranteed by design. So no need to waste cycles here for nullifying something which will be overwritten anyway.

Comment: @Darth-CodeX if he didn't append 0, then it's a bug in the first place.

Comment: I have also used `malloc` before it sometimes generates useless garbage value by default.

Comment: If you were after "safety" in first place, you would probably better consider to invest some of the CPU cycles in testing whether the allocator actually returned some memory or just NULL, which would have implications of quite elevated severity ;-)

Comment: At-least I deserve up-votes for this answer.

Comment: If that's the case, then you have an error elsewhere in you your code.

Comment: _" malloc sometimes generates useless garbage"_: `malloc` doesn't generate anything, simply the memory allocated via malloc is not initialized and it's content is undetermined.

Comment: Oh, @Darth-CodeX, what just caught my eye: what are you doing with that calculation in your calloc anyway:  `sizeof(char) * (strlen(str1) + strlen(str2) + 1)`?

Comment: @junix What is wrong with the calculation inside `calloc`??

Comment: @Darth-CodeX What's the `sizeof(char) *` portion for?

Comment: It simply multiplies `1UL` to the whole number. I have a habit of doing this, you can ignore that.

Comment: It appears to be a bit out of place if you are using calloc which describes the memory block by "number of elements" and "element size". So what's the reason for that habit?

Answer (score 0):

Anyways, after reading all your answers, this is the new code.

```c
char* mkstr(char str1[], char str2[])
{
        char* out = malloc(strlen(str1) + strlen(str2) + 1);
        strcpy(out, str1);
        strcat(out, str2);

        return out;
}

int main()
{
        char* str = mkstr("i use ","arch btw");
        printf("%s\n",str);
        free(str);

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: You may want to wrap the `strcpy/strcat` pair in a conditional block only executed if malloc returned a valid pointer: `if (out != NULL) { strcpy(out, str1); strcat(out, str2); }`